# Получение параметров запуска vk-mini-apps react приложения

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vkontakte-api, vk-mini-apps

Как я могу получить значения после # в vk-mini-apps react приложении?
Как вообще можно получить параметры запуска,например группу из которой запущен сервис?
[Документация](https://vk.com/dev/vk_apps_docs3?f=6.%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

[Скриншот 22.12.2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFx6w.png)

Comment: Значение после # можно получить через window.location.hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметры запуска можно получить таким образом:

```
const startParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
const userId = startParams.get("vk_user_id")
```

Все что идет после # будет в `window.location.hash`.

Например, если открыть приложение по такой ссылке `vk.com/app12345#info`, то:

```
window.location.hash === "#info"
```

Чтобы `URLSearchParams` работал на старых устройствах надо использовать [полифил](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill).